# взять изображение из Python в C#

Tags: python, c#, opencv, dynamic, pythonnet

Есть простой Python код:

```
import cv2
def show_img(path):
   img = cv2.imread(path)
   return img
```

Функция **show_img()** вызывается из C# используя модуль pythonnet по следующему коду:

```
Mat img = Cv2.ImRead("C:\\Users\\slorate\\Pictures\\yo.jpg");
// Initialize the Python engine
PythonEngine.Initialize();
// Load the Python script
dynamic opImageModule = PythonEngine.ModuleFromString("show_img", File.ReadAllText("helo.py"));
// We call the Python function
dynamic imgOut = opImageModule.show_img("C:\\Users\\slorate\\Pictures\\yo.jpg");
// Convert dynamic to string
//string idd = Convert.ToString(imgOut);
//byte[] bytes = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(idd);
//char[] se = idd.ToCharArray();
//Mat image = Convert.ChangeType(imgOut, typeof(Mat));
//Cv2.ImShow("s", imgOut);
//Console.WriteLine(imgOut);
```

Целью является извлечь изображение из Python в качестве переменного. Сохранить изображение потом использовать путь  - не решение проблемы, т.к. на все это тратится много времени.
Существуют ли пути к изъятию из Python изображения в C#? Те раскомментированные строки это мои попытки преобразовать тип dynamic в byte[] после чего с него пытаться получить картинку. Может есть какие нибудь другие пути решения данной задачи, поделитесь пожалуйста идеями, заранее благодарю.

Comment: Использовать [Межпроцессное взаимодействие](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Межпроцессное_взаимодействие) / [Inter-process communication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inter-process_communication). Передавать байты изображения через именованный канал (named pipe) или разделяемую память (shared memory).

Comment: Почему show_img?

Comment: @Александр, потому что метод который использую, как я понимаю, основывается на вызове функций из Python в C#. Если у вас идеи по другому это реализовать, то поделитесь пожалуйста.

Comment: Если вы можете использовать open-cv в C# зачем вам Python? А если это неудачный пример, то приведите более удачный.

Comment: @Александр, в open-cv Python-а есть обученная нейросеть для распознавания контуров в изображениях через HED Algorithm. Вот с ним как раз и работаю, Python в этом случае идёт чисто как инструмент, там быстренько распознал изображение, взял в C# и дальше работать с изображением. Да, можно в принципе всё это реализовать через "сохранить картинку > загрузить картинку", но это займет много времени.

Comment: @Александр, https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1531206/%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b0-%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d1%85-%d0%b8%d0%b7-python-%d0%b2-c