# передача данных из Python в C#

Tags: python, c#, opencv, bytearray

Мне нужно передать изображение из Python в С# преобразовав изображение в byte[].
Что я для этого использую: Я использую Named Pipe для передачи byte[] между Python и C#. Во-первых я загружаю изображение с помощью opencv-python, затем преобразую изображение в byte[]. Преобразование на мой взгляд правильное так как обратное преобразование byte[] в изображение работает корректно.
После получения byte[] изображения я отправляю как раз через Named Pipe в C#. Конкретно на этом месте у меня возникли трудности...

**Python Код**

```
import cv2
import win32file
import win32pipe
import time
import PIL.Image as Image
import numpy as np
import base64
import io

img = cv2.imread(r"-6+5_Cut.bmp")
img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
success, encoded_image = cv2.imencode('.bmp', img)
content_bytes = encoded_image.tobytes()
#print(content_bytes)
#image = Image.open(io.BytesIO(content_bytes))
#image.save("test2.png")

pipeName="CSServer"
pipe_handle = win32pipe.CreateNamedPipe(
    r'\\.\pipe\\'+pipeName,
    win32pipe.PIPE_ACCESS_DUPLEX,
    win32pipe.PIPE_TYPE_MESSAGE | win32pipe.PIPE_READMODE_MESSAGE | win32pipe.PIPE_WAIT,
    1, 65536, 65536,
    0,
    None)
win32pipe.ConnectNamedPipe(pipe_handle, None)
while True:
(_, read_message) = win32file.ReadFile(pipe_handle, 1000)
print('Received from c#: ' + read_message.decode('utf-8'))
ret, length = win32file.WriteFile(pipe_handle, **content_bytes**)
win32file.FlushFileBuffers(pipe_handle)
# win32pipe.DisconnectNamedPipe(pipe_handle)
#win32file.CloseHandle(pipe_handle)

time.sleep(2)
```

**C# Код**

```
using Emgu.CV;
using Emgu.CV.Reg;
using Emgu.CV.Structure;
using System.Drawing;
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.IO;
using System.IO.Pipes;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Text;
using System.Drawing.Imaging;
using static System.Net.Mime.MediaTypeNames;

namespace _MySpace
{
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        System.Drawing.Image img;
        using (NamedPipeClientStream pipeClient = new NamedPipeClientStream(".", "CSServer", PipeDirection.InOut))
        {

            // Connect to the pipe or wait until the pipe is available.
            Console.Write("Attempting to connect to pipe...");
            pipeClient.Connect();

            Console.WriteLine("Connected to pipe.");
            Console.WriteLine("There are currently {0} pipe server instances open.", pipeClient.NumberOfServerInstances);
            StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(pipeClient);
            //StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(pipeClient);
            while (true)
            {
                try
                {
                    sw.AutoFlush = true;
                    sw.WriteLine("Hello from c#");
                    
                    string temp = sr.ReadLine(); 
                    byte[] img_bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(temp);
                }
                catch (EndOfStreamException)
                {
                    break;                    // When client disconnects
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

**Как должен C# принимать byte[] из Python?** ////
**Или можно реализовать передачу изображения из Python в C# абсолютно по другому пути?** ////
**Поделитесь пожалуйста своими идеями.**

Comment: **Комментарии были [перемещены в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/147305/discussion-on-question-by-slorate----python--c); пожалуйста, не продолжайте дискуссию здесь.** Прежде чем разместить комментарий ниже этого, пожалуйста, ознакомьтесь с [назначением комментариев](/help/privileges/comment). Комментарии, которые не запрашивают уточнения или не предлагают улучшения, скорее всего должны быть [ответами](/help/how-to-answer), размещены на [meta] или написаны в [chat]. Комментарии, продолжающие дискуссию, могут быть удалены.